# Why can't I pass state via props to a controlled text component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused as to why React insists that I give my controlled text input components their own internal state. I followed the official documentation for creating a controlled input, and React is squawking at me via the console:

*warning.js:36 Warning: ClientInfoTextInput is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <input type="text"
        className={styles.ClientInfoTextInput}
        value={this.props.propToPass} 
        onChange={this.props.propMethodToPass}
      />
    )
```

So why can't I pass down state via props to a controlled input component without React getting upset?

Comment: It is hard to tell without the full component code being shown.  Is the component name ClientInfoTextInput?  If so I think your problem is that when this is initialized "this.props.propToPass" is undefined.  You could do a check for undefined and then pass a default value if it is.

Comment: Please show the entire file, it makes it easier for us to understand whats going on. More then likely what @ericg said is your problem but we wont know until we see more

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to debug your component without seeing the full code, but one way of passing down the state via props to a controlled input component is as follows: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/bwLjaE

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInParent: ''
    };
    this.handleTextFromChild = this.handleTextFromChild.bind(this);
  }

  handleTextFromChild(data) {
    this.setState({
      textInParent: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputForm propMethodToPass={this.handleTextFromChild}
                   propToPass={this.state.textInParent} /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class InputForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text"
               value={this.props.propToPass}
               onChange={(event) => this.props.propMethodToPass(event.target.value)} />
        <p>Text received from Parent via props: {this.props.propToPass}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Sneetches, would you like me to anything to the answer or does it give you the solution?

Comment: Yeah Piotr Berebecki, this is fine. Just as a general question, though, is it an anti-pattern for a React text input element to not have its own internal state for the input value? I ask because I've seen mention of "UI State," meaning that otherwise "presentational" elements should have their own internal state to immediately show user input changes. On the other hand, though, it seems silly for a lone input whose value is only relevant to its far ancestor to have its own internal state (as is the case in my code). So which is the correct pattern here, UI state or passing down via props?

Comment: I tend to go with advice from the React Docs and maintain a UI state. Also this may be useful for your considerations: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html where they explain that "it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that the prop is only seed data for the component's internally-controlled state". Have a look also here: http://spraso.com/managing-react-controlled-component-state/

Comment: Cool man! Now that I understand its purpose, I actually really like the idea of UI state, so I'm just going to go with that + a controlled component and pass the UI state to the parent via a props-based onClick function. Thanks a lot!